# Collision between 2 springs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, spring

Four material points, all of mass m, are aligned along a straight line and connected two by two by two equal springs, of elastic constant k and rest length $l_\epsilon$. The points are subject only to the elastic force of the springs. Initially points 1 and 2 move spaced of a distance $l_\epsilon$ and both with velocity $v_i$ directed towards points 3 and 4, that have velocity equal to 0. At the instant t = 0 point 2 collides with an elastic collision point 3.

Determine:

1. the $V_{12}$, speed of $C_{12}$, center of mass of points 1 and 2, and that $V_{34}$ of $C_{34}$, center of mass of
   points 3 and 4, in the reference of the center of mass of the 4 points, before and after the impact.
2. The equation of motion of the relative distances $x_2 - x_1$ of the points 2 and 1 and $x_4 - x_3$ of the points 4 and 3
3. the time interval of validity of the equation of motion determined above, explaining
   what happens beyond this range.

[image]

I can't express the velocity $V_{12}$ and $V_{34}$ in the reference of the center of the mass of the system, can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be whether masses 2 and 3 will stick together while the springs compress and slow 1 and 4 to a halt, or whether they will immediately rebound. They will immediately rebound.

The reason is in the words "elastic collision". All collisions conserve momentum and energy. The definition of an elastic collision is that kinetic energy is conserved. That is, no kinetic energy is converted to another form such as heat.

For many collisions (inelastic or partially elastic), some or all of the kinetic energy is converted to heat. For example, when to equal mass balls of wet clay collide, they stick together. The combined ball is at a standstill. All of the kinetic energy has gone into deforming the clay.

No doubt you have seen the outcome of an elastic collision of two equal masses. You know the speeds balls 2 and 3 would have if there were no springs. The confusing part is what difference the springs make.

For this problem, you should treat the collisions between 2 and 3 as instantaneous. The force of the springs can change the velocity of the balls, but it takes time. In the tiny time interval of the 2-3 collision, the velocity change is tiny. You can treat it as making no difference to the collision.

You have the tools to prove this to yourself. Given a ball of mass $m = 1 kg$ and a force $F = 1 N$, you can calculate how much change in velocity you get when the force acts for $0.1$ sec. Or $0.001$ sec.

Of course as soon as the 2-3 collision is over, the springs immediately to slow 2 and 3 down. You can calculate what happens.

Comment: I can't express the velocity $V_{12}$ and $V_{34}$ in the reference of the center of the mass of the system, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Think of what happens after the first collision and before the second. Do the conditions in this time period lead to a second collision? Mathematically define what a collision would mean. Could the equations give you a solution for a time when this second collision would happen? Don’t try to account for all collisions at once, but instead try to construct the entire picture one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if the balls 2 and 3 will stick together during the collision or if they will rebound. This is hard to imagine so let's look at the limit $k\rightarrow 0$. In that case the spring provides no force so it looks like there is no spring at all. We know what happen in this case. The balls 2 and 3 bounce of each other and then collide with respectively with the balls 1 and 4. So when $k=0$ the balls *do* bounce of each other.

Now we can add back a little $k$. In that case the particles still bounce but if $k$ is large enough the springs will prevent the pairs 1, 2 and 3, 4 from colliding. What happens after that you should be able to figure out after some work.